# pass multiple params onChangeText input element function - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple `Input` elements and everytime the user type into these Inputs I call `handleChange()` function which should tell what the user has written and which Input he has typed in.

This is what I have done:

```
handleChange(text, name) {
    console.log("test: "text+" "+name);
}

//http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/textinput.html
for (var p = 0; p < 20; p++){
      products.push (<TextInput name={p} onChangeText={(text, name) => this.handleChange(text, name)}></TextInput> );
}
```

the `console.log` inside `handleChange` function correctly shows the text written by user but doesn't display correctly `name` variable which results `undefined`.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html - it doesn't appear to have the 2nd param.

Comment: onChangeText by default takes the parameter value as the text entered and hence only one param. What you can try is `onChangeText{(text, p) =>  this.handleChange(text, p)}}` and see  if it works

Comment: How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is `name` supposed to be? All you're doing is setting name to an integer, but here's a way to make it work:

```
handleChange(text, name) {
  console.log("test: "text+" "+name);
}

//http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/textinput.html
for (let p = 0; p < 20; p++){
  products.push (<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}></TextInput> );
}
```

Comment: If I do like you said everytime handleChange is called p is always equal to 19, the last loop index value. Instead I want this: If I change the first input "p" (the one passed in the params along with text) should be 1, if I change the second input "p" should be 2 and so on. In my code It seems that name={p} doesn't assign "p" to name. I tried with value={p} and inputs were still empty, while if I do value="a" all 20 inputs hold "a" content. How can I assign variable "p" to name and value of inputs?

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean, the `text` variable is whatever the user inputs into the textfield. Also if you change `var p = 0` to `let p = 0` that should solve your other issue.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was doing something wrong. Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange= (name) => {
return (text) => {
   console.log("test: "name+" "+text); 
}};

[https://hackernoon.com/curry-away-in-react-7c4ed110c65a][1]

for (let p = 0; p < 20; p++){
products.push (<TextInput onChangeText={this.handleChange(p)}> 
</TextInput> );
}
```